# Blazor server-side Chartjs

Tags: chart.js, blazor-server-side

I'm using blazor server-side and trying to display a chart with Blazor.Chartjs. The problem I have is that I have the form that the user enters date and the application will get data from database with the chosen date. For the first time the chart will be displayed but when user change date and I want to chart be changed with new data but I have this error:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find a chart with the given id. c4e7005b-e203-46f1-9719-68c6d14d848f
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find a chart with the given id. c4e7005b-e203-46f1-9719-68c6d14d848f
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeWithDefaultCancellation[T](String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit '268yoqwqVBLFanukxnq3R4LjrnKrEAgIdVkQSPnIgfY'.
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find a chart with the given id. c4e7005b-e203-46f1-9719-68c6d14d848f
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeWithDefaultCancellation[T](String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

Comment: How are you trying to update the dataset for the chart? I had some difficulty with this as well recently when trying to update a Bar Chart. I tried updating the dataset in the BarConfig, but it was read-only so couldn't. I then tried recreating the BarConfig object for the chart with a new dataset. This lead me to have the same error as you, as it appears the Id that identifies the chart is tied to the BarConfig object.

In the end I had to clear the dataset in the BarConfig, create a new BarDataset object, add the updated values, and add that back to the original BarConfig object

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for a long time. I finally found that I needed to clear the dataset and add the new data back into a new dataset, then update the chart.

I am clearing the data set with:

```
_lineConfig.Data.Datasets.Clear();
```

Then I create a new version as below:

```
TempProductionLineTotal = SqlProdData.GetProductionTotals(searchDate[0], searchDate[1]);

_productionDataSet = new LineDataset<TimeTuple<int>>   
{
    BackgroundColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(System.Drawing.Color.Orange),
    BorderColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(System.Drawing.Color.Orange),
    Label = "Daily Total",
    Fill = false,
    BorderWidth = 2,
    PointRadius = 1,
    PointBorderWidth = 2,
    SteppedLine = SteppedLine.False,
    Hidden = false,
    LineTension = 0.0
};

_productionDataSet.AddRange(TempProductionLineTotal.Select(p =>
    new TimeTuple<int>(new Moment(p.DateNTime), Convert.ToInt32(p.Daily_Lineal))));

_lineConfig.Data.Datasets.Add(_productionDataSet);
```

Comment: _lineConfig.Data.Datasets.Clear(); +1
Basically don't re-initialize config object, but merely update its dataset content.